# How can I simplify the function with two loops, or is it better to leave it as it is?

Tags: c++

I have two almost identical functions where two loops are the same, but the code inside is different, how can I do it more correctly Leave it as it is or change both functions to one or how you do when faced with such code, just wondering which method do you think is correct .

```
    template <class T1>
    void function_A(T1 & array_test) {
        for (int h = 0; h < 3; ++h) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {

                // CODE 1
            }
        }
    }

    template <class T1>
    void function_B(T1 & array_test) {
        for (int h = 0; h < 3; ++h) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {

                // CODE 2
            }
        }
    }


if (functiontest == 0) {
    function_A(array_test);
}
if (functiontest == 1) {
    function_B(array_test);
}
```

I'm thinking of doing this, but I'm not sure if it's better than the top option, but inside the function there will be only code without loops, but you will also need to pass three arguments and not one

```
for (int h = 0; h < 3; ++h) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {

        if (functiontest == 0) {
            function_A(h, i, array_test);
        }
        if (functiontest == 1) {
            function_B(h, i, array_test);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can determine which function as function pointer or lambda, ... outside the loop and then call the predetermined function inside the loop. Also: if h and i are indices into the array, you could use a reference to the element or an iterator as parameter instead of the index and the array.

Comment: @Sebastian I'm afraid that the lambda will complicate the code

Comment: I would probably leave it like it is. 2 lines of similarity is too low motivation for to merge two simple functions into one that is more complex.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I think so too, so I decided to ask how others do if they write similar code.

Comment: With the upcoming (C++23, final plenary vote outstanding) (or the current ranges.v3 version of) cartesian_product and views::iota https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2374r4.html and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view you can store the 2D loop indices for the two `for` loops independently and reuse them.

Comment: Other simplifications depend on what the indices signify. Perhaps they can be automatically determined with a range based for.

Comment: @Sebastian This seems to be what I need, I'll try to study and understand, can I use it in Visual Studio now?

Comment: In VS you can for now download and use the https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3 version

Comment: Look at https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1views_1_1ints__fn.html iota, iota_view, for_each, cartesian_product_view and also https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/04/14/understand-ranges-better-with-the-new-cartesian-product-adaptor/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029428/how-to-create-a-cartesian-product-range-from-filtered-data/54030115#54030115 with a manual implementation for the product (that could even work without additional libraries by changing the headers to the C++20 ranges?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example (without template, to better show the underlying principle).
You can pass the code to test as a std::function.

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

void Test(std::function<void(int,int, std::vector<int>&)> fn, std::vector<int>& array_test)
{
    for (int h = 0; h < 3; ++h) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
            fn(h, i,array_test);
        }
    }
}

void code_1(int h, int i, std::vector<int>& array_test)
{
}


void code_2(int h, int i, std::vector<int>& array_test)
{
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values{ 1,2,3 };
    Test(code_1, values);
    Test(code_2, values);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks cool.
I'll try to use thanks, I was also interested in what Sebastian threw off
https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2374r4.html

Comment: That's cool too, this will work from C++11 onward so it might be your fallback.